# MS Access.adp to ASP.Net conversion: DLookup to SQL

Tags: asp.net

Inherited a SQL database with an MS Access .adp front end which is being converted to ASP.net VB. Using a conversion tool which has done a good job on most of it after debugging. It however could not convert DLookup functions used in combo boxes as it is not supported. Being relativley new to .net am unclear how to convert the DLookup function to a SQL statement.  The table name: dbo.Contact
The main form name: Contact_Edit
The sub form name: Contact_Edit_Sub

There are a number of combo boxes with many Dlookup functions. Once I have one I can rework the balance. Any help with converting the statement is appreciated.

The current code is listed below:

```
 *If Not IsDBNull(Me.Contact_Edit.Contact_Edit_Sub.Intake_Worker_Code) Then
                     Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = DLookup("[Name]", "Staff", "Code ='" & Intake_Worker_Code.SelectedValue & "'")
     Else
       Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = ""
    End If*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, where `[Name]` is the field and `Staff` is the table

```
SELECT [Name] FROM Staff WHERE Code = '" & Intake_Worker_Code.SelectedValue & "';
```

Here you can read more about what DLookup does:

- http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

---

Update based on comment

VB.Net SQL code sample

```
If Not IsDBNull(Me.Intake_Worker_Code) Then

    Dim conn_str As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnectionString").ConnectionString 
    Dim myconn As New SqlConnection(conn_str)
    Dim sc As New SqlCommand() 
    sc.CommandText = "Select [Name] FROM [Staff] WHERE (Code = '") & (Intake_Worker_Code.SelectedValue & "')" 
    sc.Connection = myconn 
    myconn.Open()

    Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = sc.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    myconn.Close()

Else
    Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: You are correct that the table name is Staff. My mistake. I get "expression expected" on the word "Select" in your statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure this will help.  If I can get the syntax on the first condition, I should be able to get the rest. Currently Visual Studio error = End of statement expected.                                                                                                   Sub Form_Current()
            If Not IsDBNull(Me.Intake_Worker_Code) Then
                Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text =  "Select [Name] FROM [Staff] WHERE (Code = '") & (Intake_Worker_Code.SelectedValue & "')"
            Else
                Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = ""
            End If
          End Sub

Comment: Not sure this will help. If I can get the syntax on the first condition, I should be able to get the rest. Currently Visual Studio error = End of statement expected. Sub Form_Current() If Not IsDBNull(Me.Intake_Worker_Code) Then Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = "Select [Name] FROM [Staff] WHERE (Code = '") & (Intake_Worker_Code.SelectedValue & "')" Else Intake_Worker_Code_Desc.Text = "" End If End Sub

Comment: @srw You can't do like that. Updated my answer with a code fragment giving you a hint how you need to do